# Version of C# StringBuilder to allow for strings larger than 2 billion characters

Tags: c#, 64-bit, pinvoke, stringbuilder, unsafe

In C#, **64bit Windows** + **.NET 4.5 (or later)** + **enabling `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` in the App.config file** allows for objects larger than two gigabyte. That's cool, but unfortunately, the maximum number of elements that C# allows in a character array is still [limited to about 2^31 = 2.15 billion chars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element). Testing confirmed this.

To overcome this, Microsoft [recommends in Option B](https://web.archive.org/web/20181119090643/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joshwil/2005/08/10/bigarrayt-getting-around-the-2gb-array-size-limit/) creating the arrays natively (their 'Option C' doesn't even compile). That suits me, as speed is also a concern. Is there some tried and trusted unsafe / native / interop / PInvoke code for .NET out there that can replace and act as an enhanced StringBuilder to get around the 2 billion element limit?

Unsafe/pinvoke code is preferred, but not a deal breaker. Alternatively, is there a .NET (safe) version available?

Ideally, the StringBuilder replacement will start off small (preferably user-defined), and then repeatedly double in size each time the capacity has been exceeded. I'm mostly looking for `append()` functionality here. Saving the string to a file would be useful too, though I'm sure I could program that bit if `substring()` functionality is also incorporated. If the code uses pinvoke, then obviously some degree of memory management must be taken into account to avoid memory loss.

I don't want to recreate the wheel if some simple code already exists, but on the other hand, I don't want to download and incorporate a DLL just for this simple functionality.

I'm also using .NET 3.5 to cater for users who don't have the latest version of Windows.

Comment: Actually `StringBuilder` is not a single object; it’s a chain of smaller string builders, so theoretically, the limit you are talking about shouldn’t be an issue.

Comment: @InBetween: After testing, I found the limit for StringBuilder to be around 2147483648-3500 (2^31 - 3500) characters before an `OutOfMemoryException` is produced.

Comment: Yeah, thinking on it a little more, it makes sense. Each time the string builder resizes, it adds a new builder to the chain with a capacity that doubles the total of the current chain, so yeah, in practice you run into the same wall because you’ll end up hitting the array limit. You could investigate a bit to see if there is a way to set a default expansion rate that would circumvent this but I sort of doubt there is an out of the box way to do it.

Comment: StringBuilder is some piece of code (uses internal .net stuff, etc.), and is a general purpose thing. Your requirements: 2B+ string + managed code + performance can be somewhat seen as contradictory. I guess the implementation you'll need is somehow quite dependent on these requirements (which we don't full know). I mean the optimal implementation really depends on what you'll do with such a massive thing.

Comment: Why do you need to store such a large string in memory? It may be more practical to store it in a file instead, even if it is slower. Or instead you could use multiple string builders or char arrays each under the size limit, with a class in between to handle the manipulation of data going in and out of which string builder depending on the position.

Comment: @Karl: The giant string will be analysed (e.g: checked for number of pairs of open/close braces), and also may undergo post-pro editing via custom splitting into an independent string array. These tasks will be slower if manipulation is performed via HDD (or even SSD) instead of RAM. Your idea of creating a class and using an array (or List?) of string builders or char arrays behind the scenes is one I considered. I could go that route, although an unsafe version sounds faster and was recommended by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up creating my own BigStringBuilder function in the end. It's a list where each list element (or page) is a char array (type `List<char[]>`).

Providing you're using 64 bit Windows, you can now easily surpass the 2 billion character element limit. I managed to test creating a giant string around 32 gigabytes large (needed to increase virtual memory in the OS first, otherwise I could only get around 7GB on my 8GB RAM PC). I'm sure it handles more than 32GB easily. In theory, it should be able to handle around 1,000,000,000 * 1,000,000,000 chars or one quintillion characters, which should be enough for anyone.

Speed-wise, some quick tests show that it's only around 33% slower than a StringBuilder when appending. I got very similar performance if I went for a 2D jagged char array (`char[][]`) instead of `List<char[]>`, but Lists are simpler to work with, so I stuck with that.

Hope somebody else finds it useful! There may be bugs, so use with caution. I tested it fairly well though.

```
// A simplified version specially for StackOverflow
public class BigStringBuilder
{
    List<char[]> c = new List<char[]>();
    private int pagedepth;
    private long pagesize;
    private long mpagesize;         // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040646/faster-modulus-in-c-c
    private int currentPage = 0;
    private int currentPosInPage = 0;

    public BigStringBuilder(int pagedepth = 12) {   // pagesize is 2^pagedepth (since must be a power of 2 for a fast indexer)
        this.pagedepth = pagedepth;
        pagesize = (long)Math.Pow(2, pagedepth);
        mpagesize = pagesize - 1;
        c.Add(new char[pagesize]);
    }

    // Indexer for this class, so you can use convenient square bracket indexing to address char elements within the array!!
    public char this[long n]    {
        get { return c[(int)(n >> pagedepth)][n & mpagesize]; }
        set { c[(int)(n >> pagedepth)][n & mpagesize] = value; }
    }

    public string[] returnPagesForTestingPurposes() {
        string[] s = new string[currentPage + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < currentPage + 1; i++) s[i] = new string(c[i]);
        return s;
    }
    public void clear() {
        c = new List<char[]>();
        c.Add(new char[pagesize]);
        currentPage = 0;
        currentPosInPage = 0;
    }


    public void fileOpen(string path)
    {
        clear();
        StreamReader sw = new StreamReader(path);
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = sw.ReadBlock(c[currentPage], 0, (int)pagesize)) != 0) {
            if (!sw.EndOfStream)    {
                currentPage++;
                if (currentPage > (c.Count - 1)) c.Add(new char[pagesize]);
            }
            else    {
                currentPosInPage = len;
                break;
            }
        }
        sw.Close();
    }

    // See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373365/how-do-i-write-out-a-text-file-in-c-sharp-with-a-code-page-other-than-utf-8/373372
    public void fileSave(string path)   {
        StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path);
        for (int i = 0; i < currentPage; i++) sw.Write(new string(c[i]));
        sw.Write(new string(c[currentPage], 0, currentPosInPage));
        sw.Close();
    }

    public long length()    {
        return (long)currentPage * (long)pagesize + (long)currentPosInPage;
    }

    public string ToString(long max = 2000000000)   {
        if (length() < max) return substring(0, length());
        else return substring(0, max);
    }

    public string substring(long x, long y) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (long n = x; n < y; n++) sb.Append(c[(int)(n >> pagedepth)][n & mpagesize]);    //8s
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public bool match(string find, long start = 0)  {
        //if (s.Length > length()) return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < find.Length; i++) if (i + start == find.Length || this[start + i] != find[i]) return false;
        return true;
    }
    public void replace(string s, long pos) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)  {
            c[(int)(pos >> pagedepth)][pos & mpagesize] = s[i];
            pos++;
        }
    }

    public void Append(string s)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            c[currentPage][currentPosInPage] = s[i];
            currentPosInPage++;
            if (currentPosInPage == pagesize)
            {
                currentPosInPage = 0;
                currentPage++;
                if (currentPage == c.Count) c.Add(new char[pagesize]);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The size of strings in C++ is unlimited according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3649657/4267472).

You could write your string processing code in C++ and use a DLL import to communicate between your C# code and C++ code. This makes it simple to call your C++ functions from the C# code.

The parts of your code which do the processing on the large strings will dictate where the border between the C++ and C# code will need to be. Obviously any references to the large strings will need to be kept on the C++ side, but aggregate processing result information can then be communicated back to the C# code.

[Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27298/Dynamic-Invoke-C-DLL-function-in-C) is a link to a code project page that gives some guidance on C# to C++ DLL imports.

Comment: Wouldn't 'unsafe' code accomplish the same thing more simply without the need for a DLL?