# c++ maximum std::string length is dictated by stack size or heap size?

Tags: c++, string, max

as asked in the question.
std::string myVar; the maximum character it can hold is dictated by stack or heap?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, the memory allocated for `std::string` is allocated dynamically.

Note that `std::string` has a `max_size()` function returning the maximum number of character supported by the implementation. The usefulness of this is questionable, though, as it's a implementation maximum, and doesn't take into consideration other resources, like memory. Your real limit is much lower. (Try allocating 4GB of contiguous memory, or take into account memory exhaustion elsewhere.)

Comment: ah, I thought it would be stack limited because it looks like any other local var.  I guess any std:: object is allocated in heap?

Comment: @Eugene: no, `myVar` is stack allocated, however it holds an internal buffer to store the string which is heap allocated (in general). std containers usually take an `Allocator` parameter which is in charge of allocating resources, and usually allocates on the heap, though it could (in theory) allocate on the stack.

Comment: @Eugene it depends, but for containers, yes, the data is in heap usually.  you can always hack together an allocator to "use" stack (bleh).

Comment: another related question then, is passing std::string to a function by copy would copy the holder and internal buffer to store the actual characters?

Comment: @Eugene - copying the string means copying everything. Some implementations try to delay the copy of the string internals (copy-on-write), but that is going out of fashion. Newer implementations keep small strings inside the string object and allocate dynamic memory only if the string grows above some size.

Comment: When I saw max_size, I mistook it to be the max_size being set by the user, so a bit more helpful to see it as a program: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521281/what-are-the-stl-string-limits?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

A `std::string` object will be allocated the same way an `int` or any other type must be: on the stack if it's a local variable, or it might be `static`, or on the heap if `new std::string` is used or `new X` where `X` contains the `string` etc..

But, that `std::string` object **may** contain at least a pointer to additional memory provided by the allocator with which basic_string<> was instantiated - for the `std::string` `typedef` that means heap-allocated memory.  Either directly in the original `std::string` object memory or in pointed-to heap you can expect to find:

- a string size member,
- possibly some manner of reference counter or links,
- the textual data the string stores (if any)

Some `std::string` implementations have "short string" optimisations where they pack strings of only a few characters directly into the string object itself (for memory efficiency, often using some kind of union with fields that are used for other purposes when the strings are longer).  But, for other string implementations, and even for those with short-string optimisations when dealing with strings that are too long to fit directly in the std::string object, they will have to follow pointers/references to the textual data which is stored in the allocator-provided (heap) memory.