# How long string could be read-in into string object using std::cin?

Tags: c++, string

How long string could be read-in into string object using std::cin ? 10000 characters is possible ?

Comment: @Johnsyweb into string object

Comment: See [c++ maximum std::string length is dictated by stack size or heap size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591293/c-maximum-stdstring-length-is-dictated-by-stack-size-or-heap-size). I would be surprised if 10,000 single-byte characters hit the limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cin` is a stream so virtually there is no limit to number of characters you can read.
If you buffer them all in memory you may  run out of memory, of course, then the limit is given by memory size but 10,000 characters are pretty little (~20 KB if Unicode) then far away for any limit (even on a 16 machine...).

When `cin` is OS console then there *may* be a limit to the number of characters the user can enter but it depends on the OS (anyway you unlikely will get that limit).